# How get count of value repeated in list at index position 1?

Tags: python

How to count number of values repeated in list at first position and do sum based on that

**My input :**

```
[[2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2]]
```

Note : my list will contain 2 OR 1 in first index[0]

In above the 2 is repeated the maximum number of times so my sum should be like get its second value of all and do sum and display

```
    2 , 1  -> 1 +
    2 , 1  -> 1 +
    2 , 1  -> 1 
---------------------- 
    2 , 3
```

So output would be : `2 , 3`

How to achieve above output from given Input

In my code not able to implement such logic

```
cnt=0
m[0]=0
for m in my_list:
    if m[0] == 2 
       cnt+=1
       v=m[1]
 
print(m[0],v[1])
```

Comment: Could you be more clear about your expectations and show us an example of the calculation that would output `2, 3`

Comment: @AlexandreMahdhaoui : I have edited it just need to some the values of second position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#create a list with just the 0th elements
keys = [i[0] for i in l]

#get the key that has the maximum count
max_key = max(keys, key=keys.count) 

#sum the 1st element for all sublists where the 0th element is the same as the max_key
>>> max_key, sum(i[1] for i in l if i[0]==max_key) 
(2, 3)
```

In one line (not recommended as it's not very readable):

```
>>> max([i[0] for i in l], key=[i[0] for i in l].count), sum(i[1] for i in l if i[0]==max([i[0] for i in l], key=[i[0] for i in l].count))
(2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we know 2 is the most common 1st item, here's a one liner list comprehension to make the sum:

```
[2, sum(x[1] for x in l if x[0]==2)]
#    ^    ^                  ^
#    |    |                  \-- if 1st item is 2
#    |    \-- extract 2nd item
#    \-- sum all the 2nd items
```

To find the most common 1st item, we can use collections.Counter:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(x[0] for x in l).most_common(1)  # [(2, 3)]
```

Put everything together:

```
n = Counter(x[0] for x in l).most_common(1)[0][0]
[n, sum(x[1] for x in l if x[0]==n)]  # [2, 3]
```